# How can I change (volume) hotkey permissions on debian login screen?

Tags: debian, permissions, login, keyboard, audio-volume

usually I use the laptop to hear music at home while doing things off the computer. As it is supposed, after some time of inactivity the screen saver starts on my debian (stretch) system.

To change the volume of music I have to reenter my user password to login, because at the login screen the volume hotkeys are dead, while the screen brightness hotkeys are still working. This behaviour may be superb at partys to prevent guests from manipulating the volume - but everytime I get a phone call I have to reenter the whole password just to have the permission to mute/unmute the music.

I spent some time at the internet figuring out how to add permissions to the volume hotkeys to be working at login screen like the screen brightness hotkeys. I have not found any hint.

edit: Its a "stock" Debian Stretch installation on a Thinkpad T400, except for using Gnome Classic mode as user interface.

```
[output of uname -a]
Linux debian 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

[excerpt of hwinfo]
  description: Notebook
    product: 6474D88
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: ThinkPad T400
    serial: 
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=notebook family=ThinkPad T400 frontpanel_password=unknown keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled

*-multimedia
  description: Audio device
  product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 1b
  bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
  version: 03
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
  configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
  resources: irq:33 memory:fc120000-fc123fff


[output of modinfo]
Module                  Size  Used by
option                 53248  0
uas                    24576  0
usb_wwan               20480  1 option
qmi_wwan               28672  0
usbserial              49152  2 option,usb_wwan
usb_storage            73728  1 uas
cdc_wdm                20480  1 qmi_wwan
usbnet                 45056  1 qmi_wwan
mii                    16384  1 usbnet
fuse                   98304  3
ctr                    16384  2
ccm                    20480  1
rfcomm                 77824  2
bnep                   20480  2
binfmt_misc            20480  1
uvcvideo               90112  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
coretemp               16384  0
arc4                   16384  2
iwldvm                139264  0
mac80211              671744  1 iwldvm
iTCO_wdt               16384  0
kvm                   593920  0
iTCO_vendor_support    16384  1 iTCO_wdt
pcmcia                 65536  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
r852                   20480  0
sm_common              16384  1 r852
nand                   61440  2 r852,sm_common
nand_ecc               16384  1 nand
nand_bch               16384  1 nand
pcspkr                 16384  0
bch                    24576  1 nand_bch
r592                   20480  0
evdev                  24576  14
nand_ids               16384  1 nand
memstick               20480  1 r592
joydev                 20480  0
mtd                    65536  3 nand_bch,sm_common,nand
btusb                  45056  0
iwlwifi               151552  1 iwldvm
yenta_socket           49152  0
i915                 1257472  12
pcmcia_rsrc            20480  1 yenta_socket
pcmcia_core            24576  3 yenta_socket,pcmcia,pcmcia_rsrc
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
cfg80211              589824  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
bluetooth             552960  31 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
snd_hda_codec_conexant    24576  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
sg                     32768  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
mfd_core               16384  1 lpc_ich
serio_raw              16384  0
drm_kms_helper        155648  1 i915
snd_hda_intel          36864  8
drm                   360448  10 i915,drm_kms_helper
snd_hda_codec         135168  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec_generic
shpchp                 36864  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
snd_hda_core           86016  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_generic
mei_me                 36864  0
mei                   102400  1 mei_me
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               110592  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
thinkpad_acpi          86016  0
nvram                  16384  1 thinkpad_acpi
snd                    86016  23 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,thinkpad_acpi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
rfkill                 24576  7 bluetooth,thinkpad_acpi,cfg80211
wmi                    16384  0
ac                     16384  0
battery                20480  0
button                 16384  1 i915
video                  40960  2 thinkpad_acpi,i915
acpi_cpufreq           20480  1
parport_pc             28672  1
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              24576  0
x_tables               36864  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
ext4                  585728  2
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
jbd2                  106496  1 ext4
crc32c_generic         16384  2
fscrypto               28672  1 ext4
ecb                    16384  0
lrw                    16384  0
glue_helper            16384  0
ablk_helper            16384  0
cryptd                 24576  1 ablk_helper
aes_x86_64             20480  3
mbcache                16384  3 ext4
xts                    16384  3
gf128mul               16384  2 lrw,xts
algif_skcipher         20480  0
af_alg                 16384  1 algif_skcipher
dm_crypt               28672  1
dm_mod                118784  9 dm_crypt
sd_mod                 49152  3
psmouse               135168  0
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_i801               24576  0
libata                249856  2 ahci,libahci
i2c_smbus              16384  1 i2c_i801
scsi_mod              225280  5 sd_mod,usb_storage,libata,uas,sg
firewire_ohci          40960  0
sdhci_pci              28672  0
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_pci
mmc_core              147456  2 sdhci,sdhci_pci
firewire_core          65536  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
xhci_pci               16384  0
xhci_hcd              188416  1 xhci_pci
ehci_pci               16384  0
thermal                20480  0
uhci_hcd               45056  0
ehci_hcd               81920  1 ehci_pci
e1000e                249856  0
usbcore               253952  15 usbnet,uvcvideo,usb_storage,ehci_hcd,qmi_wwan,uhci_hcd,cdc_wdm,usbserial,xhci_pci,btusb,option,uas,usb_wwan,xhci_hcd,ehci_pci
ptp                    20480  1 e1000e
pps_core               16384  1 ptp
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
```

Comment: I would advise adding some technical data to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I added system information as technical data I assume to be helpful :)

Comment: Workaround: https://askubuntu.com/a/142726/100386

Comment: Can you just set the screen saver timer to a higher value while you’re at home? Or have a second account, that you use only for playing music at home, that has a higher screen saver timer (and/or a simpler password)?

Comment: There's a Gnome extension called "Caffeine" that keeps the screen awake and unlocked once you click on the icon.